# Is there a way to get data from multiple Activity in a single Fragment?

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment in a User Activity that opens up a Map Activity to receive some string variables.The fragment Has Already Recieved 2 String Variables from the User Activity using Bundles.

This is my Method for doing such but i keep getting that error :

**And this is the error i get that kick me out**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project_seraphim_disease_tracker, PID: 17049
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, 
request=66738, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity 
{com.example.project_seraphim_disease_tracker/com.example.project_seraphim_diseas
e_tracker.User}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

**These are in both Map Activity and the Fragment that's in User Activity**

```java
private static final String SEARCHED_ADDRESS = "searched_address";
private static final String SEARCHED_NAME = "searched_address_name";
private LatLng SearchedLocationlatLng;
private String SearchedlocationAddress;
private String SearchedlocationName;
```

**This is the button that called to a Map activity from a fragment which is in User Activity**

```java
btnAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Map.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,IDENTIFIER);
    }
});
```

**This is what i used to Receive the Strings**

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case (IDENTIFIER) : {
            if (resultCode == Map.RESULT_OK) {
                SearchedlocationAddress=data.getStringExtra(SEARCHED_ADDRESS);
                SearchedlocationName=data.getStringExtra(SEARCHED_NAME);
                editTextSearchLocationBar.setText(SearchedlocationName);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is in the Map Activity for passing the strings**

```java
btnConfirmAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra(SEARCHED_NAME,SearchedlocationName);
        resultIntent.putExtra(SEARCHED_ADDRESS,SearchedlocationAddress);
        setResult(Map.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();

    }
```

Comment: if you look at the logs you posted you can see a null pointer exception: it looks like the issue is that the edit text is not set (it's null) when your onActivityResult() runs. are you sure you're setting `editTextSearchLocationBar` to the view it should be?

Comment: Yeah that was the part of the problem. Fixed that after searching for a while. I also find my solution to this problem I'm having. All i had to do is call onActivityResult in the User Activity and pass the data to fragment from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was found on this old post but it still works.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449850/13594169

basically When i call startActivityForResult in a fragment the parent activity (Inmy case the User Activity get to handle the data first) Then from there i have to pass the data to the fragment.

Imagein Activities as the parent **A** and **B** and Fragment in **A** as the child **A.1**. 
Child **A.1** request data from parent **B**. Parent **B** give the data to parent **A**, after parent **A** receive the data, then it will pass it to child **A.1**.

**So after Calling from fragment A.1**

```
startActivityForResult(intent,IDENTIFIER);
```

**put this in Activity B for passing the required data**

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra(key_word,String);
setResult(Map.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

**put this in activity A To handel the data received from activity B**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(childTag);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
//If you have your child Fragment as a private member, 
//then use Fragment fragment = myChildFragment;
//to replace the above findFragmentByTag line of code. The rest can be kept unchanged
```

**Then put this in fragment A.1 to receive the data orgin from Activity B**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case (IDENTIFIER) : {
            if (resultCode == Map.RESULT_OK) {
                //Assign data
                //Update Ui
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```